# How to have radio button behaviour for divs while using angular?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

So I'm starting with angular and I would like filter a list depending on which div is currently selected.

They are selected by being cliked. I suppose this is exactly how radio buttons behave but they are ugly and I would like to have a completely designed div (not just label) which is to be clicked.

I've read that you can add label with for attribute and hide the radio button to have something similar. I suppose what I would like is to be able to add `for` on a div to bind it.

What would be the best way to achieve this  *The Angular Way* ?

Answer (score 2):

You will find your solution at [angular ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons) bootstrap goto buttons sections

Comment: I am working on a project where we musn't use bootstrap for styling